# Linux networking bridge not forwarding manually created packet

Tags: ip, bridge, mac-address

I am trying to implement packet forwarding using a BPF-program. The idea is to forward a suitable packet from `veth1` (ingress) directly to `veth2` (egress). The problem I am facing is that the redirected packets seem to be dropped by the bridge `v-net-1`. I have been analyzing the traffic with Wireshark and the packets leave from `veth2` and enter at `veth2-br` just as intended but never reach `veth3-br`.

Now there are a few things where I do not really understand why they are happening.
The first would be that when I turn off my BPF-program and let the user-space-program build the packet the destination IP address of the packet is the one of the bridge (`192.168.11.10`), however the way I understood IP addresses was that they are end-to-end i.e. there should be the IP address of the client in the packet (`192.168.11.1`) and only the MAC addresses would change while routing the packet.
The second one would be that a packet created by my BPF-program, which has the exact same MAC and IP entries, is not sent to `veth3-br`, while one created by the user-space-program is sent there. The UDP-port is the only thing that differed between my tries but as far as I understand it that cannot be the reason for a drop since the bridge is not considering l4 protocols.

The setup looks like this:

```
   _______________________________________              ______________________
  |            Relay namespace            |            |   Client namespace   |
  |    ______________   ______________    |            |     ____________     |
  |   | 192.168.10.2 | | 192.168.11.2 |   |            |    |192.168.11.1|    |
  |___|____veth1_____|_|____veth2_____|___|            |____|____veth3___|____|
                              \                                   /
                               \                                 /
                                \                               /
                                 \                             /
                                __\ _________________________ /
                               /veth2-br|            |veth3-br\
                               |                              |
                               \__________v-net-1_____________/
                                             /
                                   ip: 192.168.11.10
                                   net: 192.168.11.0/24
```

the link info of the relay namespace is:

```
9: veth1@if8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a2:85:a2:09:2a:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
14: veth2@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ce:b8:3f:d5:f3:17 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

the link info of the global namespace is:

```
10: v-net-1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:06:cb:05:65:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: veth3-br@if12: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master v-net-1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a6:bc:ae:a2:75:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns client_ns
13: veth2-br@if14: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master v-net-1 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:85:99:6c:80:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns relay_ns
```

the link info of the client namespace is:

```
12: veth3@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f2:51:1c:4c:2b:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

and the bridge forwarding database looks like that:

```
33:33:00:00:00:01 self permanent
01:00:5e:00:00:6a self permanent
33:33:00:00:00:6a self permanent
01:00:5e:00:00:01 self permanent
33:33:ff:05:65:62 self permanent
01:00:5e:00:00:fb self permanent
33:33:00:00:00:fb self permanent
d6:06:cb:05:65:62 vlan 1 master v-net-1 permanent
d6:06:cb:05:65:62 master v-net-1 permanent
```

Comment: This is an interesting question, but without a complete reproducer I'm not sure we'll be able to help.

Comment: I guess posting all the code that leads to this problem might be a bit too much. What would be an appropriate way of sharing things that might help others understand it? Also, I found that the IP checksum seems to be wrong in the packet created by my program even though I used the BPF_F_RECOMPUTE_CSUM flag. I reckon a packet with a wrong checksum would be dropped by the bridge and could cause this behavior?